# Jenkins RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy with OIDC and externally managed role assignments

Tags: jenkins, roles

I am trying to find a way to use the roles I manage in Okta to work with Jenkins. I have been trying to get [role-strategy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/role-strategy-plugin) plugin to work, but when I log in, I get `<user> is missing the Overall/Read permission`.

My configuration includes OIDC for Okta, using `oic-auth` plugin, and I am specifying the authorizationStrategy config via JCasC. For example I have this on my JCasC okta.yaml:

```
authorizationStrategy:
  roleBased:
    roles:
      global:
        - name: "my_okta_group"
          permissions:
            - "Overall/Administer"
```

I see this properly getting converted into `$JENKINS_HOME/config.xml`.

What I don't specify, but seems to be required, is `assignments:`, because - it's RBAC after all, and the user assignments into roles should be made in Okta, not Jenkins.

After browsing the plug-in code, it appears hard-wired for an explicit user SID list to be specified in the JCasC. That's not going to work for me.

Is there a different way to use this plug-in to achieve the goal?

Is there another RBAC plug-in that would work better?

Answer (score 0):

The above is very close to a working solution. `assignments:` is indeed required, and it supports username or **group**. Also the 'name' of 'authorizationStrategy.roleBased.roles' is the Jenkins role name, not the OIDC group name.

The oic-auth configuration maps OIDC token fields to Jenkins user properties, and then the role-strategy checks for the OIDC token's username, as well as its group(s).

My working config is:

```
jenkins:
  securityRealm:
    oic:
      clientId: "${clientId}"
      clientSecret: "${clientSecret}"
      wellKnownOpenIDConfigurationUrl: "${oidcIssuerUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration"
      userInfoServerUrl: "${oidcIssuerUrl}/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
      tokenFieldToCheckKey: ""
      tokenFieldToCheckValue: ""
      fullNameFieldName: "name"
      groupsFieldName: "groups"
      disableSslVerification: false
      logoutFromOpenidProvider: true
      endSessionEndpoint: "${oidcIssuerUrl}/oauth2/v1/logout"
      postLogoutRedirectUrl: "https://${dns_name_full}"
      escapeHatchEnabled: false
      escapeHatchUsername: ""
      escapeHatchSecret: "my-unused-password"
      escapeHatchGroup: ""
      automanualconfigure: "auto"
      emailFieldName: "email"
      userNameField: "name"
      tokenServerUrl: "${oidcIssuerUrl}/oauth2/v1/token"
      authorizationServerUrl: "${oidcIssuerUrl}/oauth2/v1/authorize"
      scopes: "address phone openid profile offline_access groups email"
    
  authorizationStrategy:
    roleBased:
      roles:
        global:
          - name: "my_jenkins_role"
            permissions:
              - "Overall/Administer"
            assignments:
              - "my_okta_group"
```

BTW, I specify the yaml with Helm:

```
...

  JCasC:
    configScripts:
      okta: |
        jenkins:
          securityRealm:
            ...
```